# How to get the thread's scheduling policy from console

Tags: c, linux

Is this possible to figure out thread's scheduling policy from linux console? I mean is it possible to receive something what `pthread_getschedparam()` returns but from console?

I need to figure out whatever policy is `SCHED_FIFO, SCHED_RR or SCHED_OTHER`.

Comment: I doubt it. Because threads are internal to processes and the kernel has little know-how about how the processes set the priority.

Comment: @code What do you mean by 'receive it from the console'?

Comment: Without access to source just knowing the pid of process. I know that it is easily possible to list all threads within given process. Is it possible to list them with scheduling policy attribute as well (using ps, top or whatever)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command **ps -eLfc** will give you a list of threads running along with their scheduling policy under the row titled **CLS**. RR (Round Robin), TS (Time Sharing) are some of the scheduling policies that may be present.
If you want to start a process and mention a particular scheduling policy for its threads then you can use command **chrt**.